# How to fix different python versions errors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, flask, mod-wsgi

I have 3 different versions:

```
2.7, 3.5, 3.6
```

To install Flask and run Hello World, I followed this tutorial step by step [Flask](http://www.brettjouwstra.me/flask_and_apache/)
But I changed this command `ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python` To:

```
ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python
```

and now it is giving me this error in the log:

```
[Fri Apr 20 09:21:19.808894 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 25752:tid 139701099587456] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Apr 20 09:21:19.808980 2018] [core:notice] [pid 25752:tid 139701099587456] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Apr 20 09:21:32.207980 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 25752:tid 139701099587456] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Apr 20 09:21:33.319127 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 26013:tid 140126648674176] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.5.1+.
[Fri Apr 20 09:21:33.319205 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 26013:tid 140126648674176] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.5.2.
[Fri Apr 20 09:21:33.320002 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 26013:tid 140126648674176] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/3.5.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Apr 20 09:21:33.320024 2018] [core:notice] [pid 26013:tid 140126648674176] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Apr 20 09:28:37.277698 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 26013:tid 140126648674176] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Apr 20 09:28:38.336490 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 10166:tid 140069159778176] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.5.1+.
[Fri Apr 20 09:28:38.336542 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 10166:tid 140069159778176] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.5.2.
[Fri Apr 20 09:28:38.337272 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 10166:tid 140069159778176] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/3.5.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Apr 20 09:28:38.337294 2018] [core:notice] [pid 10166:tid 140069159778176] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Apr 20 09:29:08.182299 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 10166:tid 140069159778176] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Apr 20 09:29:09.224956 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 10290:tid 140446016731008] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.5.1+.
[Fri Apr 20 09:29:09.225001 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 10290:tid 140446016731008] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.5.2.
[Fri Apr 20 09:29:09.225714 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 10290:tid 140446016731008] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/3.5.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Apr 20 09:29:09.225740 2018] [core:notice] [pid 10290:tid 140446016731008] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Apr 20 09:29:42.886467 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 10294:tid 140445919373056] [client 134.193.130.121:56046] mod_wsgi (pid=10294): Target WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python modul$
[Fri Apr 20 09:29:42.886529 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 10294:tid 140445919373056] [client 134.193.130.121:56046] mod_wsgi (pid=10294): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi'.
```

What I understood is that Flask module was not found. I changed the version again, and now I am so lost. What to do to get `"Hello World"` Work?

Comment: i would recommend using something like Conda or Pyenv to manage different versions of python

Comment: Thanks @chrisz I am using virtualenv. Doesn't that do the same job?

Comment: That is a really bad idea! Traditionally `/usr/bin/python` is linked to your python 2.x installation and `/usr/bin/python3` is linked to python 3.x. If your operating system uses python 2.x, its python scripts will now fail. Ifyou are using virtualenv, the right python is setup when the env in enabled. Except you still have to know when its `python` verses `python3`.

Comment: I will agree with @chrisz pyenv is simple enough to use and easy.

Comment: @SpirosI.Oikonomakis Thanks man, but still my question isn't virtualenv does the same thing ? I mean based on separating the python version?

Comment: `venv` creates isolated Python environments for Python libraries. `pyenv` is used to isolate Python versions. so imagine if you want to test something in multiple versions somehow you should be able to switch between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those logs do not show the actual error and why your app doesn't load. You need to see the messages after what you included.

The warning about Python patch level can be ignored, as is documented at:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/installation-issues.html#python-patch-level-mismatch

If you want to use Python 3.6, you must use a mod_wsgi installation which has been compiled for 3.6. There is no way to force mod_wsgi compiled for 3.5 to use 3.6.

You should uninstall the system package for mod_wsgi. Then compile mod_wsgi from source code yourself against the Python 3.6 and use it. Easiest to use `pip install` method:

- https://pypi.org/project/mod_wsgi/

Then run `mod_wsgi-express module-config` to get config to include in Apache configuration. Or use `mod_wsgi-express start-server` if just doing local development. See the documentation at that link.

You can not use `pyenv` with mod_wsgi unless you take the extra steps to ensure `pyenv` generates shared libraries for Python, which it doesn't do by default.

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate that. Could you please provide a good blog or a page to understand WSGI more for beginners! (I am using Flask). Thanks again.

Comment: Are wanting to know about WSGI specification, or are you talking about a mod_wsgi, which is just one WSGI server/adapter implementation. For WSGI you can start with www.wsgi.org. For mod_wsgi see www.modwsgi.org. If is WSGI, you really are better off starting with a framework on top, as using raw WSGI is no fun.